# List elements with actions

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to create an application which shows some list with elements (say) Item1,Item2,Item3..
And when click on Item1 ,a new screen with list elements Item11,Item12,Item13... must show
And same in the case of Item2 and Item3.

If any one knows a solution Plz help...

Answer (score 1):

hey try these links for custom list fields:

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Create_a_colour_ListField.html?nodeid=1166318&vernum=0

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-ListField-row-with-images-and-text/m-p/227993/highlight/true#M35022

Moreover i believe from wherever u are getting the data u place it in an array or vector.

try to google and search forums you will get what u want
:)